# Force scrolling to the last group in an xceed DataGridControl

Tags: c#, xceed-datagrid

Im having an issue caused by the virtualization of xceed grids.  I have a button that expands/collapses all groupings.  The problem is, it only works on what has been virtualized in the grid.  I was thinking a solution would be to force a scroll down to the bottom forcing all groups to be loaded, and then perform the expanding collapsing.  I know you can BringItemIntoView on xceed dataGridControls but im not seeing a way to do this for groups.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to have to scroll down in order to expand/collapse all groups and sub-groups.

The code snippet I provided in your other question should do the trick:

[Expanding all groups, including nested, in an xceed DataGridControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36519828/expanding-all-groups-including-nested-in-an-xceed-datagridcontrol)